Exterior light fixtures mud-in j-box
Exterior light fixtures mud-in j-box
Hello! Has anyone installed exterior sconces with the j-boxes hidden behind the siding? I know it’s an unconventional way to install exterior lights but trying to figure out a clean way to install them without having a box shown.
Something similar to this but on exterior siding: https://www.mullanlighting.com/us/thames-outdoor-spot-light/?___store=us&___from_store=en

The usual solution is to have the junction box mounted flush, or nearly flush, with the siding. It can't end much (1/4"?) behind the siding because the siding is presumed to not be rated for the 120V (or 240V) electrical wiring. For aesthetic reasons you generally don't want the box to protrude from the siding much because then it will be visible when the light fixture is installed.
The light fixture is then screwed into the box so that the back of the fixture - hopefully metal - acts as a cover for the junction box. A nice light, as opposed to an "industrial" flood light or similar, will have an outer cover that (a) looks nice and (b) is a little bit larger than the junction box so that the junction box is hidden.
I spot-checked a number of different brands/types on Home Depot and they all work similarly.
There is also a real code problem. Any junction box must be accessible - i.e., be able to get to the wiring inside it with nothing more than removing the fixture or a screwed-on cover plate. To have a junction box totally hidden as in the sample product link, you would need to have the junction box accessible inside the house, which would be rather unusual.
